# Another ajax request fail

Tags: html, ajax

I have a very strange experience dealing with my Ajax request in local host.

History :

I have one laptop and one PC. Both has the same Xampp server installed. When I work on laptop my Ajax request is working normal. But when I work on PC, all Ajax request is 'working' in php side, but return no response and colored by red in console for Ajax request.

Investigating :

I found that in my PC when I right click and View Page Source I got this additional script inserted in the top of my webpage :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ><script src="http://cakecdn.info/adtest.js?v=151116&ch=1"></script>
<head> // now colored by red.
```

When I mouse-over to head tag the message says *the element of the same type was already open*

Another strange thing was : When I click a button ( that trigger the Ajax request) very soon after the page refresh, the Ajax request is working good. By doing this I just though trying to make a request before the 'strange' script not yet finish dancing. But next after that all Ajax request was back to no response.

Question :

What actually happen?

If suppose that my PC is infected by any malware, it will be ok for me cause I can recover it. Just wondering if any users that has infected PC and running my website, all Ajax request will fail.

Any helps is deeply appreciated.

Comment: charset utf-8 with BOM usually cause this problem. Try **changing all your PHP source files in the editor to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM"**. Any invisible characters generating at the top of the HTML might make the browser assume an unknown head element. Let me know how it goes

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa I have tried to save it in notepadd++ without BOM, but still remain the same. Most websites that opened in my PC has inserted script after html tag. Virus in my PC?

Comment: is it the same script generating on all the websites ?

Comment: Try making adjustments to your `default.ctp`. have a look at [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904372/cakephp-2-this-html-script-order) to get some idea. and Don't wry I hardly think its some virus, it just looks like some cakePHP configurational issue.

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa yes for the one using HTML5

Comment: Just hopping this problem will not happened on live server. I have tried to open any websites from my PC and I saw the inserted script there, they have no Ajax request problem. Thanks Nikhil for your comment

Comment: Hope it works well on live. Cheers